# Customize Preference Activity - How to add option to browse FS, select a file/resource and save the reference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I need some help customizing my Preference Activity in Android. I would like to add a custom preference option that allow the user to browse into the file system and pick a file (an image). After he selects something he gets redirected back to the Preference Activity that will save the URI of the resource the user selected. I hope that I made myself clear, it should be something like that:

MyApp ---> Settings ---> Press "Select Image from Disk" ---> Browse FS ---> Select Image ---> Go back to my app that meantime will save the URI of the resource selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to launch the built-in gallery by using an **intent**.

I suppose you know how to code the preference itself with a listener.

Run the following code when the desired preference is clicked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,INTENT_ID_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

This should open the gallery and return the URI of the selected image in onActivityResult().

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if(requestCode==INTENT_ID_SELECT_IMAGE){
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                //do with uri what you like
                Toast.makeText(this, "image selected: "+imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```